# Importing MSN contact list

Tags: java, list, contacts, msn

How to import import Msn contact in our application?

I want to learn about importing msn contact list in my java appication.
Need help on this and where can i find the sample java code for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Java MSN Messanger Library:

This is the link to the download:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-jml/files/java-jml/jml-1.0b4/jml-1.0b4.jar/download

And this is the link to their homepage:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml